# android tablelayout DrawingOrder:Draw focused child at the last

Tags: java, android, draw, tablelayout

in my layout,i want to make the focused item an highlight background that will overlap on siblings,so i implement a CustomDrawingOrderTableRow like this:

```
public class CustomDrawingOrderTableRow extends TableRow{...

super.setChildrenDrawingOrderEnabled(true);
...

protected int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int currentPos) {
    return Util.getFocusedChildDrawLastOrder(this, childCount, currentPos);
}


    Uitl.java:
public static int getFocusedChildDrawLastOrder(ViewGroup vg,
        int childCount, int iter) {
    View focusedView = vg.getFocusedChild();
    if (focusedView == null) {// no focused child
        return iter;
    }
    // index of the focused child
    int index = vg.indexOfChild(focusedView);
    if (iter == childCount - 1) {// last draw the focused child
        return index;
    } else if (iter >= index) {
        // Move the children after the focused child earlier one
        return iter + 1;
    } else {
        // Keep the children before the focused child the same 
        return iter;
    }
}
```

but the drawing order is not changed whether there is focused child or not.

How to make a focused child draw in the end in a Tablelayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question is right,the problem is that code never executed.

I finally figure it out that i have to call

```
parentContainer.requestLayout();
```

in the OnFocusChangeListener to make the whole contianer re-draw,so the code in the question will be executed.